# SQL Server : REVOKE GRANT OPTION from a user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005;

There is a database and a table in it called `myTB`.

There are two users `user1` and `user2`.

`user2` can log in and set some permissions, for example he can execute this:

```
DENY permission ON myTB TO user1
or 
GRANT permission ...
```

Now the problem is that I want to restrict `user2`; he shouldn't have the permission to `GRANT` or `REVOKE` or `DENY` any permissions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any roles set up? Typically GRANT and DENY would be reserved for sysadmins/DBA - they would have a role entitling them to do that. Other users would not have those permissions, but might still be able to modify data, and even alter tables (outside a production environment!)

What does user 2 need to be able to do?

Comment: Do you want the `WITH GRANT` option?

Comment: @penguat user2 should just be able to read the myTB ! he shouldn't be able to change his or other's permissions !

Comment: the grant permission is previously granted to user2 ! NOW how can I revoke this permission which is previously granted !?